# Can't insert data in mongodb with insertOneAsync

Tags: c#, mongodb

I want to insert data into a mongodb database. It worked like a charm, but I have one collection where I can't insert in the database and I don't know why. I do literally the same.

This doesnt work here

```cs
public async Task AddVerifyAsync(VerifyModel verifyModel)
{
       verifyModel.CreationDate = DateTime.Now;
       await _context.Verifies().InsertOneAsync(verifyModel);

}
```

I checked it multiple times, ran the debug mode, checked the model etc, it is all absolutely correct. 
This is the method which returns the collection:

```cs
public IMongoCollection<VerifyModel> Verifies()
{
     return _database.GetCollection<VerifyModel>("VerifyModel");
}
```

These are the methods that are working:

```cs
public async Task AddUserAsync(UserModel user)
{
       await _context.Users().InsertOneAsync(user);
}
```

The collection-returner is just the same as above but with the other types.
I even have tried to remove the DateTime thing. Also I set the `_id` before giving it to the `AddVerifyAsync` method. But I even have tried disabling that.

the `_context` is dependency injected in the constructor.
This is where both methods get used:

```cs
public async Task CreateUserAsync(UserModel user)
        {
            UserModel gotUser = await _userRepository.GetUserByEmailAsync(user.Email);
            //check if exists
            if (gotUser != null)
                throw new DataException();

            //set defaults and prevent, that the user tries to manipulate data
            user.Active = false;
            user.RegTimeStamp = DateTime.Now;
            user.AdminLevel = 0;
            user.OrganizationId = null;
            user.OrganizationAdminLevel = null;
            user.Password = BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.HashPassword(user.Password);
            user.Balance = 0f;
            user.ProfilePicture = "";
            //Add the user to the repo
            await _userRepository.AddUserAsync(user);
            VerifyModel verifyModel = new VerifyModel();
            verifyModel.UserId = user.Id;
            verifyModel.Id = ObjectId.GenerateNewId().ToString();
            //useractivation
            verifyModel.Type = 0;
            //insert the verifyuser in database
            await _verifyRepository.AddVerifyAsync(verifyModel);
            await _emailSenderService.SendMailAsync(user, EmailTemplate.RegisterMail, verifyModel.Id,
                "Herzlich Willkommen bei flundr. Nur noch ein Schritt!", user.Email);
        }
```

Here the Verifymodel doesnt get inserted in the db.

Comment: Sorry for trivial question, but did you await `AddUserAsync`?

Comment: Yes I did. I did multiple awaits

Comment: Can you paste the codes of `UserModel`, `VerifyModel`, the place where both of them used in same manner, how the `_context` is injected/generated/newd.

Comment: Added it in the original question. Hope that helps

Comment: Is _verifyRepo's interface is set in the injection modul as same as _userRepo's? I used to forget that.

Comment: Yes exactly. So CreateUserAsync is in the class UserService and I injected verifyRepo and userRepo

Comment: Ok. So there is a `services.AddTransient/Singleton<IVerifyService, VerifyService>();` in somewhere for example

Comment: Yes it is an asp.net application. If I would use it without that I would instantly get an exception

Comment: So I just created a new controller and called the verifyRepository directly. And it doesnt create anythin neither.. Lol..

Comment: I don't see anything trivial. What is the code of `VerifyModel`?

Comment: Okay... It was my mistake... I had a task which deletes the models in the database but which malfunctioned... So I inserted and every 5 seconds all entries got deleted.. Thank you very much for your time and help :)

Comment: Tricky question :D maybe I use it in interview (not)